# How do I use git submodules to keep one preamble template for all my documents?

Tags: templates, revision-control, preamble

I’ve read [this](http://markelikalderon.com/2008/07/31/keeping-your-latex-preamble-in-a-git-submodule/) which outlines the advantages of using submodules in git to use one centralized preamble .tex to be used for all future LaTeX document. When the preamble is changed, all documents compiled subsequently are affected.

This sounds great, but the git part is very poorly explained, and I haven’t had any luck finding a guide that does this successfully. I even bough the Peepcode guide, but it’s pretty bad.

I know this is a part-git-part-LaTeX question, but the question is specifically directed at LaTeX work management.

Answer (score 1):

What is your exact problem?

The situation is as follows:

- One main repo with the preamble
- Several working repo's with a submodule connection to the main repo
- Every time something changes in the main repo, every repo using it will have to run `git submodule update` to retrieve those changes.

For more information about submodules check the [git submodule tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial).